# Where do we actually assign the best move during Minimax?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have a decent understanding of how minimax and alpha beta pruning works in terms of returning the 'best value'.  However I am unsure where the 'best move' should be assigned.

I know that the best move needs to come from the original board passed in, and since I am looking for a maximum value it must be assigned under the maximizing player.  However using my current code causes best action to be reassigned over and over again.
e.g. If the original board is O--\n---\n---, then the best action becomes
OX-\n---\n---, then reassigned to O-X\n---\n--- and so on.

```
public int minimax(Board board, int depth, boolean maximizing,int alpha,int beta) {
    int bestValue;
    if (board.isTerminal()) {
        bestValue = board.calculateValue();
    } else if (maximizing) {
        bestValue = alpha;
        for (Action action : board.makePossibleActions()) {
            int childValue = minimax(board.makeCopy().takeAction(action),depth+1,false,bestValue,beta);
            if (bestValue <= childValue) {
                bestValue = childValue;
                if (board.equals(originalBoard)) {
                    bestAction = action;
                }
            }
            bestValue = Math.max(bestValue,childValue);
            if (beta <= bestValue) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        bestValue = beta;
        for (Action action : board.makePossibleActions()) {
            int childValue = minimax(board.makeCopy().takeAction(action),depth+1,true,alpha,bestValue);
            bestValue = Math.min(bestValue,childValue);
            if (bestValue <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bestValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You know the root is a max player.
2. You also know the depth (0 or 1, depending on how you make the initial call).

So, if the max player is to play, you are at the root of the tree, and the value of the max move is updated, then also store the move in a class variable to return. (Instead of taking the max, test to see if the value is greater and then update the max and the best move together.)

Answer (score 0):

A practical minimax algorithm implementation requires some of these features depending upon the complexity of the game.

1) A low level implementation of the board to allow quick analysis of the positions and generation of valid moves.

2) A hash table to enter evaluated score and move for each hashkey, which will also assist during force move.

3) A move table to enter all previous moves with corresponding hashkeys to help avoid repeated moves and assist in undo and redo moves.

4) Since a responsive GUI user interface is required, the minimax algorithm may be implemented in the background, preferably on another thread.

5) Iterative deepening search will be required practically as a player may like to use force move or vary the game level.

So, after the best move is evaluated, I would prefer to pass on the result to the main calling thread.